# Hiding by default posts in given category except for some cases

Tags: categories, filters

I have assigned to some posts a sort of "archived" category hence these posts shouldn't appear anywhere except when users access the "archive" page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would note that this will be a very slow/expensive query. It's much faster to ask for every category except that one, than it is to filter out that specific category. The most efficient method would involve tagging everything as 'not archived' and only showing things in that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wpse276485_exclude_archived($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && !is_category('archived') ) {
    $query->set('category__not_in', array(get_cat_ID('archived')));
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse276485_exclude_archived');
```

That should do it, assuming the name of your category is "archived".

Comment: Is this a "heavy" approach, as stated by Tom J?

Comment: Heavier than the inverse. Whether it falls under the bounds of acceptable performance or not is down to you to decide, try loading a page with and without that action hook and compare the performance with something like [Query Monitor](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/).